Complete matrix using column names in external vector
I have a data frame and an external vector that contains strings that are some of the column names in my data. I would like to use the external vector in a complete function on my data. I know how to do that with select() and data masking functions, but can't figure out how to run the same with complete().
Example:
library(dplyr)

df <- expand.grid(Sex = c("Male", "Female"), Year = 2015:2020, Colour = c("red", "green")) %>%
    filter(Sex == "Female" | Year > 2017)
vars <- "Sex"

df %>% select(any_of(vars))
df %>% filter(pick(any_of(vars)) == "Female")

How do I write this, but using vars instead of Sex?
df %>% complete(Sex, Year, Colour)


df %>% complete(!!rlang::sym(vars), Year, Colour)?

Awesome. Do you want to write up the answer? I'd be happy to accept! rlang is still a mystery to me...

I think df %>% complete(.data[[vars]], Year, Colour) would be the current recommendation.
